# LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> output the element side by side?

Tags: java, linked-list, printf, 2d

I have a problem. I cant output my LinkedList side by side. I asked this question but sadly my Teacher told me to not change the method head or use the libary of java like calender. I got many advice of using it or change the method head. I am Depending on the grade and the teacher is very strict.

**There must be somehow the possibility to output a 2 Dimensional LinkedList from left to right. I can imagine the way one can say if an element from the Generic of LinkedList is outputed then please go further to the right.**

I am struggeling at the implementation of this Idea. I hope you can help me.

Here I just returning a String but for testing I output the string what is get added.

```
public String getYearplan(int from, int until) {
    if (from <= until) {
        for (int i = from; i <= until; i++) {
            LinkedList<String> buildedMonth = buildMonth(i);
            this.planlist.add(buildedMonth);
        }
        for (LinkedList<String> months: planlist) {
            for (String s : months) {
                System.out.printf("%24s",s);
            }
     }
}
```

`
In this method buildMonth I am building the Month and return a LinkedList what get added by this.planlist .

```
 public LinkedList<String> buildMonth(int month) {
            LinkedList<String> monthList = new LinkedList<>();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String header = this.monthname[month] + " " + this.year;
            sb.append(header);

            int lengthOfMonth = calender.getLengthOfMonth(jahr, monat);

            for (int day = 1; day <= lengthOfMonth; day++) {


                for (int weekday = 0; weekday < 7; weekday++) {
                    String weDay = kalender.getDayOfWeek(weekday);
                    this.weekDayName = weDay;
                }
                this.daynumber++;
                String dayOfMonth = this.kalender.getTwoLetter(day);

                /*
                  modus = -1 is calender without holiday
                */
               if (this.modus == -1) {
                    sb.append("\n"+this.weekDayName+"|"+dayOfMonth.toString()+"|\t\t|"+daynumber);
                }
            }
            monthList.add(sb.toString());

            return monthList;
        }`
```

This is my output what I get and everything works without some stuff but it is easy to fix. The major problem is that I cant Output it side by side.`The weird thing is that the header of february is moving to left but not the other elements.

```
    January 2017
    Sa|01|      |1
    Sa|02|      |2
    Sa|03|      |3
    Sa|04|      |4
    Sa|05|      |5
    Sa|06|      |6
    Sa|07|      |7
    Sa|08|      |8
    Sa|09|      |9
    Sa|10|      |10
    Sa|11|      |11
    Sa|12|      |12
    Sa|13|      |13
    Sa|14|      |14
    Sa|15|      |15
    Sa|16|      |16
    Sa|17|      |17
    Sa|18|      |18
    Sa|19|      |19
    Sa|20|      |20
    Sa|21|      |21
    Sa|22|      |22
    Sa|23|      |23
    Sa|24|      |24
    Sa|25|      |25
    Sa|26|      |26
    Sa|27|      |27
    Sa|28|      |28
    Sa|29|      |29
    Sa|30|      |30
    Sa|31|      |31February 2017
    Sa|01|      |32
    Sa|02|      |33
    Sa|03|      |34
    Sa|04|      |35
    Sa|05|      |36
    Sa|06|      |37
    Sa|07|      |38
    Sa|08|      |39
    Sa|09|      |40
    Sa|10|      |41
    Sa|11|      |42
    Sa|12|      |43
    Sa|13|      |44
    Sa|14|      |45
    Sa|15|      |46
    Sa|16|      |47
    Sa|17|      |48
    Sa|18|      |49
    Sa|19|      |50
    Sa|20|      |51
    Sa|21|      |52
    Sa|22|      |53
    Sa|23|      |54
    Sa|24|      |55
    Sa|25|      |56
    Sa|26|      |57
    Sa|27|      |58
    Sa|28|      |59`
```

Thats is the Output what I try to achieve.`

```
  January 2017            February 2017           
  So|01|            |1    Mi|01|            |32  
  Mo|02|            |2    Do|02|            |33   
  Di|03|            |3    Fr|03|            |34   
  Mi|04|            |4    Sa|04|            |35    
  Do|05|            |5    So|05|            |36    
  Fr|06|            |6    Mo|06|            |37
```

I hope it was not much, but I wanted to make my question this time clear.
Best Regards
Maskulin

Comment: You're going to have to iterate your print statement by something other than each month at a time. Essentially you're going to want to print this by day (Jan 1st, then Feb 1st, etc.) This would be easy if all months had the same amount of days, but they don't, but I would still start here and try to do some error checking (maybe write a helper method) to determine if you should print the information contained in the list for that day, or if you should just tab over because the day does not exist

Comment: Could probably just add another dimension of for loops that iterates through i from 0 to 30 (for all the days) and then inside of that loop iterate through your months like you are doing. Then do try catch blocks to check if the index is out of bounds and tab over if the exception is met

Answer (score 1):

Iterating through the days at a higher dimension than the months I think is the way to go. That way, you can iterate through each day and list them all before going onto the next day for each month.

The below has not been tested but I hope the concept has been exemplified.

```
    public String getYearplan(int from, int until) {
        if (from <= until) {
            for (int i = from; i <= until; i++) {
                LinkedList<String> buildedMonth = buildMonth(i);
                this.planlist.add(buildedMonth);
            }
            for (int day = 0; day < 31; day++){
                for (LinkedList<String> month: planlist) {
                    try{
                        System.out.print(month[day]);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.print("\t")
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: It just print it out like the same, but now it has some empty lines.

Comment: It shouldn't be printing out identical... That doesn't really make much sense. Make sure you are not adding a newline after each print statement

Comment: I using month.get(day) instead of month[day]. Actually it is the same but with these empty lines